# Как конвертировать элемент результата запроса в денежный формат?

Tags: mysql

У меня есть такой запрос:
    SELECT m, y, point, predprijatie, title, sum(prihod)
    FROM prihod
    GROUP BY m, y, point, predprijatie, prihod
Как сделать, что бы поле sum(prihod) выводилось в денежном формате?

Comment: Повторяешься. [О формате результата запроса с плавающей точкой][1].

  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/70479/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если речь идет о Delphi, то для того, чтобы сконвертировать число с плавающей запятой в денежный формат достаточно функции `Format()`

```
Format('%2.2m', 1234.777); // Вернет 1 234,78 р. или 1 234,78 грн. или другой вариант
```

Денежная единица и ее положение после или перед числом зависит от настроек операционной системы клиента (Панель управления - Язык и региональные стандарты).

Если нужно прописать жесткий вариант формата можно сделать так:

```
Format('%2.2n грн.', 1234.777); // Вернет 1 234,78 грн.
```

Если вывод числа в определенном формате рассматривается в случае с использованием источника данных TDataSet (TQuery, TTable и т.д.), то наиболее удобный вариант - установить обработчик OnGetText для нужного поля в этом DataSet-е.

Код обработчика может выглядеть так:

```
procedure TForm1.Table1Field1_GetText(Sender: TField; var Text: String; DisplayText: Boolean);
begin
  if DisplayText then
  begin
    Text := '';
    if (Sender.AsVariant <> Null) then
      Text := Format('%2.2m', [Sender.AsFloat])
  end;
end;
```

Смысл этого обработчика в том, что число в источнике данных остается числом, а выводится оно как форматированная строка.

Answer (score 1):

Представление данных - дело приложения.
Если говрить про Delphi, у класса TField есть свойства DisplayFormat и EditFormat для установки формата отображения и редактирования соответственно. Можно сделать например так:

```
TFloatField(DataSet.Fields.FieldByName('FIELD_NAME')).DisplayFormat := '0.00, руб';
```

тогда во всех компонентах, которые будут отображать твое поле, FIELD_NAME будет в таком виде. Детали можно посмотреть в хелпе.

Answer (score 0):

```
CAST(SUM(prihod) AS DECIMAL(20, 2))
```

20 и 2 - число знаков до и после **.**

Comment: Почему то не получается. Т.е. не выводит результат в формате "00.00"...

Comment: А как выводит? Возможно, где-то значение все-таки преобразуется в целое после извлечения из БД

Comment: да, честно говоря, ни как не меняется... результат у меня получается и целое и с плавающей точкой. Дело в том, что этот запрос в проекте дельфи и результат запроса выводится в DBGrid. В случае, когда я выводил значения в Label я делал так:
FMain.Label24.Caption := FloatToStrF(StrToFloat(uDatas.ADQPrihodRashodMainSUMprihod.Value) , ffCurrency, 30, 2);
Но, как мне форматировать результат в DBGrid, я что то не пойму.